# Complex SQL to ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i'm getting a lot confused by includes hashes and joins in Active Record, i would like to know how i can do this kind of query on Rails

```
SELECT 
p.name,
o.id AS order_id,
op.id AS order_product_id,
op.name
FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN order_products AS op
ON op.order_id = o.id 
INNER JOIN product_providers AS pp
ON pp.id = op.product_provider_id 
INNER JOIN providers as p 
ON p.id = pp.provider_id 
WHERE o.id = 1
```

Comment: Can you explain  your question?

Comment: Sure, i want to somehow translate this sql query to an activerecord query, something like `Order.where(id: params[:id]).joins(example: {[:e1, e2]}, e2]) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the following relationships:

--An order has many order_products,

--An order_product has one (belongs_to) product_provider,

--A product_provider has one (belongs_to) provider

If those relationships are correct, then you would want something like this:

```
Order.joins(order_products: {product_provider: :provider})
     .where(orders: {id: 1})
     .select('orders.id AS order_id, order_products.id AS order_products_id, order_products.name')
```

Though you are not selecting anything from `product_providers` or `providers`, so not sure why you want to join them.